# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL - I'm not using any frameworks

Tags: sql-server, jsp, servlets

I'm getting

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL error
>   in my application

. Please see the three files and advice me what's wrong with me.

**URL:**

http://localhost:8080/ccrf/admin/ComplaintServlet.do?txt_frm_date=01-04-2015&txt_to_date=30-04-2015&select_dept=1&btn_get_data=

ComplaintServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/ComplaintServlet")
public class ComplaintServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String frm = request.getParameter("from").trim();
        String to = request.getParameter("to").trim();
        String c = request.getParameter("dept");    
        int dept = 0;
        dept = Integer.parseInt(c);

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN_CCRF","sa","developer1");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Complaints WHERE ComplaintDept=? AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ComplaintDate,105) BETWEEN ? AND ?");
            ps.setInt(1,dept);
            ps.setString(2,frm);
            ps.setString(3,to);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                pw.println("<table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th>Title</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>asd</td></tr></tbody></table>");
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            pw.println("Class Not Found. "+e);
        }catch(Exception e){
            pw.println("Failed. "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewComplaints.jsp

```
 <%@ page import="servlets.DBConnection,java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.io.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Consumer Complaints Redressal Forum</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='../css/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='../css/style.css' rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src='../js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<!-- datepicker-->
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- end datepicker-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#txt_frm_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val();
        $('#txt_to_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val();
    });
/*  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_get_data').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : '../admin/com.do',
            data : {
                from : $('#txt_frm_date').val(),
                to : $('#txt_to_date').val(),
                dept : $('#select_dept').val()
            },
            success : function(response) {
                //$('.op').html(response);
                alert(response+'as');
            }
        });
    });
});*/
</script>
    <div class='container'>
        <%@include file="header.jsp"%>
        <div class='main'>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
               <div class="panel-body">
                    <% if(session.getAttribute("USER_NAME") == null || session.getAttribute("USER_NAME") == "" || session.getAttribute("USER_TYPE") == "U"){%>
                        You don't have permission to access this page..!
                    <%}else{%>
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <a href='index.jsp' class='h pull-left'>Home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; You are logged in as <strong><%=session.getAttribute("USER_NAME")%></strong> (<a class='logout' href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>)
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form class="form-inline" role="form" name='frm-get-data' id='frm-get-data' method='GET' action='../admin/ComplaintServlet.do'>
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_frm_date" name='txt_frm_date' placeholder='From Date:'>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_to_date" name='txt_to_date' placeholder='To Date:'>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <select class="form-control" name='select_dept' id='select_dept'>
                                        <%
                                        response.setContentType("text/html");
                                        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                                        try{
                                            DBConnection conObj = new DBConnection();
                                            Connection conn = conObj.DbCon();
                                            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Departments ORDER BY DeptID");                      
                                            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                                        %>
                                            <option value=0>ALL</option>
                                        <%
                                            while(rs.next()){
                                                //pw.println(rs.getString("DeptName"));
                                        %>  
                                            <option value=<%=rs.getString("DeptID")%>><%=rs.getString("DeptName")%></option>    
                                        <%
                                            }
                                        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                                            pw.println("Class Not Found. "+e);
                                        }catch(Exception e){
                                            pw.println("Failed to retrieve departments. "+e);
                                        }
                                        %>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" name='btn_get_data' id='btn_get_data'>Get it!</button>
                            </form>
                            <div class='op'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <%}%>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xsi:schemalocation="http:/java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ComplaintServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.ComplaintServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ComplaintServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/ComplaintServlet.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBConnection</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.DBConnection</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBConnection</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DBConnection</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is the URL that throws that 405 status? Paste it in the question

Comment: Could you try `http://localhost:8080/admin/ComplaintServlet.do?txt_frm_date=01-04-2015&txt_to_date=30-04-2015&select_dept=1&btn_get_data=` and `http://localhost:8080/ComplaintServlet?txt_frm_date=01-04-2015&txt_to_date=30-04-2015&select_dept=1&btn_get_data=`

Your URL pattern in the annotation `@WebServlet` OR the pattern in `web.xml` should match the URL you are hitting the app with. Neither of them seem to match because of the `/ccrf/` in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Serving the app under `/ccrf/` virtual directory is causing your URL patterns defined in web.xml and `@WebServlet` to not match with actual URL. You got 2 options:

- Either serve your app in the root and access it like `http://localhost:8080/admin/ComplaintServlet.do?txt_frm_date=01-04-2015&txt_to_‌​date=30-04-2015&select_dept=1&btn_get_data=`
- Or change your URL patterns in web.xml to include `/ccrf/` prefix like `<url-pattern>/ccrf/admin/ComplaintServlet.do</url-pattern>`

Comment: I've changed my wex.xml as you said. But now I'm getting requested resources not available error - 404. My WEB-INF folder is under root directory (ccrf) and I'm tryin to access the servlet from a folder named admin inside the root directory. Please advice me.